# AsyncTask + NFC вылет приложения при дебаге

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask

Была проблема с отображением ProgressBar'а во время процесса считывания/записи в тэг NFC. Она решилась использованием AsyncTask, но появилось взамен ещё две)
Сам код.

```
   private void CancelAsyncTask(){
        mt.cancel(true);
    }

   byte[][] bufbuf;

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Ndef, byte[][], Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            setVisibilityProgressBar(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Ndef... params) {
            try {
                bufbuf = readFromNFC(params[0]);
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e){
                CancelAsyncTask();
                /*mTvMessage.setText("Ошибка чтения. Попробуйте ещё раз.");
                setVisibilityProgressBar(false);*/
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(bufbuf != null) {
                mTvMessage.setText("Успешно");
                setVisibilityProgressBar(false);
                passReadData(bufbuf);
            } else {
                mTvMessage.setText("Ошибка чтения. Попробуйте ещё раз.");
                setVisibilityProgressBar(false);
                CancelAsyncTask();
            }
        }
    }
```

При обнаружении тэга, создаётся новый Intent в котором вызывается следующая функция:

```
  public void onNfcDetected(Ndef ndef){
        try {
            mt = new MyTask();
            mt.execute(ndef);

        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

Функция чтения из тэга:

```
   @Nullable
    private byte[][] readFromNFC(Ndef ndef) {

        try {
            ndef.connect();
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
            if(ndefMessage != null) {
                byte buf[][] = new byte[ndefMessage.getRecords().length][];
                for (int i = 0; i < ndefMessage.getRecords().length; i++) {
                    buf[i] = ndefMessage.getRecords()[i].getPayload();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "readFromNFC: " + "success");
                ndef.close();

                return buf;
            }

            else{
                Log.d(TAG, "readFromNFC: " + "NFC tag null");
                //mTvMessage.setText("Ошибка чтения. Попробуйте ещё раз.");
                return null;
            }

        } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //mTvMessage.setText("Ошибка чтения. Попробуйте ещё раз.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Функция passReadData передаёт данные из DialogFragment (в котором и лежат все эти функции), в активити (так что она нам не сильно интересно).

Суть работы программы. Из активити, по нажатию кнопки вызывается фрагмент. При нахождении тэга NFC запускается функция OnNfcDetected, считываются данные из тэга, передаются в активити. Активити запускает второе активити и передаёт 
в него данные. Второе активити обрабатывает данные и заполняет лайаут (таблицу).
Во время Debug'а программа вылетает (но если идти последовательно по всему циклу обработки, всё нормально). Если просто запускать приложение Run'ом, то никаких проблем не возникает. Если убрать AsyncTask и передавать данные одним потоком - проблем так же нет.
Логи ошибок:

```
05-08 13:07:04.042 25870-25875/com.init_plus.nfc_configurator A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:681] Check failed: threadId != 0u (threadId=0, 0u=0) 
05-08 13:07:04.193 25870-25875/com.init_plus.nfc_configurator A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Runtime aborting...
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Aborting thread:
05-08 13:07:04.194 25870-25875/com.init_plus.nfc_configurator A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingForDebuggerSend (still starting up)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xe9247500
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=25875 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf3129920
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=26 stm=5 core=1 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xf302b000-0xf302d000 stackSize=1022KB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #00 pc 00351e09  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #01 pc 00332325  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+304)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #02 pc 003252d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+24)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #03 pc 00325159  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+424)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #04 pc 0031bee7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+90)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #05 pc 000b4dcb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+866)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #06 pc 00240135  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEy+708)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #07 pc 0023f981  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+76)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #08 pc 0023f411  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+180)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #09 pc 002430b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1016)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #10 pc 000e47d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+560)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #11 pc 000e4431  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1016)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #12 pc 000e500b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+658)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #13 pc 000d2685  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+132)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #14 pc 00134625  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art19HInstructionBuilder25IsOutermostCompilingClassEt+528)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #15 pc 00133fc3  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder16BuildNewInstanceEtj+626)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #16 pc 0012f11b  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+3522)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #17 pc 0012de1d  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+1176)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #18 pc 00112c3d  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+84)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #19 pc 001571c9  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+2452)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #20 pc 00158e03  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+330)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #21 pc 00107ebf  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+194)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #22 pc 002505c3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+318)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #23 pc 00251ce7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+430)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #24 pc 003451e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+44)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #25 pc 00344d21  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+64)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #26 pc 00047f93  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #27 pc 0001a161  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   (no managed stack frames)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] All threads:
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] DALVIK THREADS (16):
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75922698 self=0xf3a05400
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=25870 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf6c3e534
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=84 stm=13 core=2 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xff7dc000-0xff7de000 stackSize=8MB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #00 pc 00351e09  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #01 pc 00332325  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+304)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #02 pc 00344477  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+622)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #03 pc 00332eb5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21RunCheckpointFunctionEv+144)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #04 pc 003f614d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+52)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #05 pc 003f60ef  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+8)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #06 pc 002df629  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_content_res_AssetManager_applyStyle__JIIJ_3I_3I_3I+212)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.content.res.AssetManager.applyStyle!(Native method)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.obtainStyledAttributes(ResourcesImpl.java:1189)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   - locked <0x064435de> (a android.content.res.Resources$ThemeKey)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:2364)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:612)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4475)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1025)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1019)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1015)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1011)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at com.init_plus.nfc_configurator.Tabs.createSeek(Tabs.java:1626)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at com.init_plus.nfc_configurator.Tabs.Fill_table(Tabs.java:1204)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at com.init_plus.nfc_configurator.Tabs.PageNameArray(Tabs.java:1155)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at com.init_plus.nfc_configurator.Tabs.onCreate(Tabs.java:298)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
```

Не все, ибо итак портянка получилась. Куда здесь смотреть, чтобы выявить негодяя, который всё крашит? В силу неопытности даже не представляю на что смотреть и где проблема.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.